# Solana wallet connection issue when initialize the transactions

Tags: transactions, solana-wallet-adapter, phantom-wallet

HereBy sharing the set of codes and console of the error log.I have tested all scenarios and modules, and it works perfectly on the Solana localnet with the frontend. However, when we change the network to devnet, the following errors occur when trying to connect the Phantom wallet with the functions.
Please let me know what we need to do next.

And attaching the screenshots for reference :

[Solana localnet source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv0TJ.png)

[image: Solana devnet source code]

[image: Solana error console for the above codes]

Comment: The error `ProgramFailedToComplete` means that your on-chain program panicked somewhere during execution. You'll need to read through the program logs to debug the issue. You can try adding your program so that someone can help debug, but that would probably be better in a new question.